# Login on Jasperserver with php

Tags: php, soap, jasperserver, vtiger

I have an open source CRM system (vTiger) Now I want add a button and when I click on that button it opens my jasperserver url , but already logged in with username and password I provide through php...

How can I login with PHP in jasperserver? Is that possible. I saw a lot of examples to run reports with php, but I just want to login..

Comment: found it:
https://URL:8443/jasperserver/home.html?j_username=$username&j_password=$password

Comment: correction:
"URL/jasperserver/home.html?j_username=$username&j_password=$password"